# Detect and extract data from a chat room, even if the data that been enter in the chat room is the same

Tags: javascript

I need extract data from a chat room, here my code:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector("div.chatbox>ul").children[25];

// later, you can stop observing
if (observer) observer.disconnect();

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.target.tagName === "EM") {
          console.log("type:",mutation.type);
          console.log("\ntarget",mutation.target);
          console.log("\nusername:",target.querySelector("span.username").lastChild);
          console.log("\nnewMsg:",target.querySelector("em.massage").lastChild);
      }
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree:true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

I can get the data from the element, the problem is that when the same data is enter in twice or more, the event does not go off. How to get data that is enter into the chat room and are the same which cause no event. No control over how the data is coming in dynamically, I have no control or access on when the data is inserted into the DOM, I can only just query the chat room messages starting with the last element. only a certain amount of element is appended before the chat room start to reuse those element, so like 25 elements are appended and after those 25 element get use over again to show messages. I even query the strings as textNode and add a property to in a setInterval function to check if these two textNode the same, but I started to see incorrect variation in the log out of the messages. I been working on this for a week now. I would appreciate it if someone can give me a helping hand.

MORE INFO:

So the messenger works like this: a center number of div is in one div as a chatbox. Depending on the messaging coming in a center number of divs get taking from the top and push into the bottom. Any suggestion?

Comment: In which case you need to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to hack something to gather to better learn html css and js. I have a chatbox I found somewhere on the web and want to copy the message being push from what I would think a setTimeout. I been beat my head on it multiple time on this and exhausted myself on it but I still like to figure it out to better my understanding of how html work aka dom and css work aka cssom and how js work.