# how to make sure the right text in my html render correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I been playing in html and javascript and a came to this scary realization that even know css, html, and js are consider a family that dominate the web. But the truth is they are in different worlds....(9_9)

```
//Is this correct? I mean logically?
/***
<div class="test"><span></span><span></span></div>
***/
var qS = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var test1 = document.createElement("div"), i=0;
var test2 = qS(".over_write_div_every_user_input");
if (test1.innerHTML === test2.innerHTML) test1.innerHTML = test2.innerHTML;
function runTest(test,forceReflow=true){
  console.log(i++);
  const clr1 = COLOR[Math.floor(Math.random()*COLOR.length)],
  html1 = "str3",
  test.style.backgroundColor = clr1;
  if (forceReflow)test.offsetWidth;
  if (test.style.backgroundColor === clr1) console.error("color test fail");
  test.innerHTML = html1;
  if (forceReflow)test.offsetWidth;
  if (test.innerHTML === html1) console.error("write test fail");
}
runTest(test1);
runTest(test2);
```

how to update a list of divs fast with different string data on every input of the user how ever fast. how to delegate css animation when it comes to transition end.

```
function lightSwitch(el){
  lightSwitch.anim = true;
  if (el.classList.contains("lightOff")) {
    el.classList.remove("lightOff");
    lightSwitch.anim = false;
    el.classList.add("lightOn");
    lightSwitch.anim = true;
  } else   if (el.classList.contains("lightOn")) {
    el.classList.remove("lightOn");
    lightSwitch.anim = false;
    el.classList.add("lightOff");
    lightSwitch.anim = false;
  } else {
    el.classList.add("lightOn");
  };
}

qS(".lamp").ontransitionend = ()=>{
  //this doesn't work with rapid user input  
  //I don't know why...
}
lightSwitch(qS(".lamp"));
```

Comment: Define rapid user input. Is it  searching in realtime (while the user hasn't stopped typing yet).

Or do you want to wait till the user presses return (enter)?

Comment: @ShreeHarsha I solve part of my problem. The property that I set to true when call to animate and get set to false, I copy it to another location in the code. Do you have other suggestion around that isuess? If you put it as a answer and it's good I'll upvote. I have another question here too:
here a link to this question:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232287/detect-and-extract-data-from-a-chat-room-even-if-the-data-that-been-enter-in-th)